# iOS - how do I force two labels to be the same length?

Tags: ios, storyboard

I know how to do it if they are stacked vertically, but I have a "row" of three objects in my storyboard - a Label, a Picker of width 50, and a second Label.  The first label has static text; the second label begins with no text, but that changes dynamically based on the Picker's value.  I have constraints set as follows:

20 from the view's left edge to Left Label's left edge

20 from Left Label's right edge to Picker's left edge

20 from Picker's right edge to Right Label's left edge

20 from Right Label's right edge to the view's right edge

The three objects are aligned vertically by their centers, and it is 20 from 
the view's top edge to Left Label's top edge.

I want Left Label and Right Label to be the same width regardless of what is in Right Label, but when I run the app, Right Label gets all of the "additional space" in the width.  If I lower Left Label's Content Hugging Priority, it gets all of the space (and Right Label's width corresponds to its content).

Is there a way of forcing the two labels to have equal widths in Storyboard, or is this something that has to be handled in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Select both labels
- In the `Add New Constraints` popup check `Equal Widths`

Comment: "Equal Widths", eh?  (BTW, it works - thanks for the answer)